# How do I determine the performance of a shader?

Tags: performance, opengl

On the CPU you can easily find the time it takes for something to execute. For example something along these lines.

```
start_time = time();
doSomething();
delta_time = time() - start_time();
```

However I have no idea how to do this for openGL since it I need to know how long things took to execute on the GPU not the CPU. How do I for example find out how long a shader took to execute in milliseconds?

Comment: "*How do I for example find out how long a shader took to execute in milliseconds?*" How long it took to execute one invocation or a batch of work?

Comment: Have you tried [OpenGL Timer Queries](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/opengl-timer-query/)?

Comment: YUP that worked great for me thank you!